# Scala sys.env for undefined environment variables

Tags: scala, environment-variables

This expression

```
sys.env("HOME")
```

delivers the path to a home folder; in general `sys.env("EnvVar")` delivers the value associated to `$EnvVar`. However, for an environment variable `$LIB` not declared

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: LIB
```

How to find out whether the variable is declared without having to catch an exception ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`sys.env` is a `Map`, so you can call its `get` method, which returns an `Option`:

```
scala> sys.env.get("FOO")
res0: Option[String] = None
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try this:

```
  val value = sys.env.get("EnvVar")

  println(value.getOrElse("Your default value"))
```